# How to group nested data in GraphQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, graphql, express-graphql

```
{
  "data": {
    "books": [
      {
        "name": "Himu",
        "genre": "novel",
        "author": {
          "name": "Humayun Ahmed",
          "country": "Bangladesh"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Tatina",
        "genre": "novel",
        "author": {
          "name": "Zafor iqbal",
          "country": "Bangladesh"
        }
      },

      {
        "name": "Show Me",
        "genre": "novel",
        "author": {
          "name": "Nick Pirog",
          "country": "United States"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have this data I want to display all the books of authors who live in a specific country
(e.g. all books of all authors living in Bangladesh). I am new to GraphQL and I don't know how to do that. I am using node.js with MongoDB.

```
const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Book",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    genre: { type: GraphQLString },
    author: {
      type: AuthorType,
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Author.findById(parent.authorId);
      },
    },
  }),
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    books: {
      type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Book.find({});
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: please make an attempt before asking for help

Comment: I tried last few hours

Comment: please provide your attempt in the question

Comment: when I try to post my attempt, it shows It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

Comment: make a [mcve] to share